# How do I use Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2019 to connect my project to a new repository instead of the existing one on Github?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer

How do I use Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2019 to connect my project to a new repository instead of the existing one on Github?

I have tried having a look at it. It seems like it might have something to do with Remotes in Team Explorer but I am not sure and I do not want to break anything.

My Team Explorer:
[image: TeamExplorer]

Answer (score 1):

If the repository has been pushed to a different project and you just want to change where fetch/push talks to, then click the Edit link there in Repository Settings and update the origin URL.  Then fetch/push will be directed to the new repository.

Hope this helps.